# Is it possible to make exceptions to Apache auth?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

So in my VirtualHosts file I have the typical Apache authentication with

```
<Directory /srv/www/site>
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "This site has restricted access"
    AuthUserFile /srv/www/users
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

But for instance I want to test transactional emails and it seems the authentication is preventing images from being loaded in those (because there's no way for the client to authenticate).

So my question is, is it possible to make exceptions for certain file extensions?

In my case the extensions .png, .jpg, .svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest mechanism I'm aware of is creating another `.htaccess` file inside the pictures subdirectory:

```
Satisfy any
```

This will effectively add an exception for the whole directory. I suppose you can fine-tune it with the `<Files>` directive if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I just made another <Directory> for the subdirectory that held the images and added that line

Comment: That's right, `<Directory>` is basically the `httpd.conf` equivalent of what I wrote. Thanks for reporting back.